# What encryption mechanism is used in CouchDB?

Tags: encryption, couchdb

Does anyone know about what type of encryption is used to store data securely on CouchDB? How one can change/control this encryption mechanism for data security on CouchDB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CouchDB does not encrypt data at rest (except passwords, by way of a [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) one-way hash).

It does allow the encryption of data in transit, by use of [HTTPS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146), but for at-rest encryption, your options are:

- Device/filesystem-level encryption. This is handled by your OS, and is completely invisible to CouchDB (and all other apps).
- Application-level encryption. You can have your application encrypt data before marshaling it to JSON for storage in CouchDB. The [crypto-pouch](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch) plugin is one example of this, which works for PouchDB (Note: I've never used it, so can't vouch for its usefulness).

Comment: If you additionally want to encrypt data at rest, [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/implement-custom-solution-kubernetes-cluster-couchdb-ibm-cloud/) is a good tutorial.